instagram.com unreachable through SQUID proxy
I got VPS with Squid on it. And have faced with strange problem.
All social media site working properly facebook, youtube etc. But https://www.instagram.com is unreachable with the proxy from my home station.
And when i try to curl https://www.instagram.com right from VPS using same proxy address (localhost) it DOES work, and i see index page of insta!
I cant catch difference between executing curl command through ssh right on server and through proxy remotely from my home station.
anybody please heeeelp me!
